# Oauth2 server redirect URI

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth2-server

My question may seem silly, but I really do not understand - what the purpose of catching redirect_uri from request and compare it with URI specified in the clients table? Is it due to a security issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pre-registering redirect URIs itself is a security measurement because the authorization requests in OAuth 2.0 are not signed. Attackers could phish the user in clicking a link that would result in an authorization request with a redirect_uri pointing to a site that they control.

Sending the `redirect_uri` in the request itself does not serve a security purpose but is just there to let the Authorization Sever know where the client wants to receive the authorization response in the case there are multiple redirect URIs registered for this particular Client.

The `redirect_uri` parameter is optional by spec anyhow. If there's only one registered, then the `redirect_uri` parameter may be omitted from the request.  If multiple redirect URIs are registered and no redirect URI is provided in the request, the result is unspecified: the AS may pick the first, anyone or none of them.

Comment: So, I have to compare only host of the redirect_uri specified in request?

Comment: No because parts of the website or host that the redirect_uri is on may be controlled by others than the client. Strict matching is best security wise.

Comment: But if the redirect uri in the request must strict match with uri already registered in my server, why i can not use it (uri specified in my server) for redirecting?